# Vim: Warning region not supported

Tags: linux, vim, manjaro

I'm setting up my .vimrc but I encountered a problem with spell checking. Here is my .vimrc:

```
setlocal spell spelllang=en_us,fr_fr
```

In the editor, the spell check seems to work properly for both languages, but the problem is that before it opens vim I got "Warning: region fr not supported".

Is there a way to make this warning message disappear?

Comment: seems that the region `fr` does not exists... try to go with `fr` without any region

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there a way to list all the available regions?

Comment: there are depending on your installation. there is a spell folder in your `$VIMRUNTIME` Folder. Run `(vim -e --cmd 'echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' 2>&1)` to see the location

Comment: @jww such as [vi.se]...

Comment: Next time I will! Thx for letting me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer by [Doktor OSwaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5276188/doktor-oswaldo):

"fr" region does not exist, replace `fr_fr` by `fr` fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious but I couldn't find a list of regions on the [vim documentation for spell](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html) and since British English is `en_gb`, I assumed French would be `fr_fr`.